# addslashes() function in PHP is not able to replace all ' in my string

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, addslashes

I am trying to use txt file hosted at http://terriblytinytales.com/test.txt in php.
I am saving all individual words in a database using mysql.
I am using `addslashes()` function like this

```
$txtFile = addslashes(file_get_contents('http://terriblytinytales.com/test.txt'));
```

But after successfully saving in the database, the ' in the string I got by `file_get_contents('http://terriblytinytales.com/test.txt')` is not replacecd.

only the first ' in we're is replaced and others are same.
Please help

Comment: How do you see which ones got replaces? And why do you need that? Can you share the **full** code you are using?

Comment: Er... The `addslashes()` PHP function has very limited use cases and storing text into databases is definitively not one of them. What do you need slashes for?

Comment: @NicoHaase I am using `alert()` in my front end code to see the string after using `addslashes()`
I need to add slashed before ' so that I can save words with ' in my database without any problems
link to see my code https://github.com/crownedlake/TTT/blob/master/scan.php

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I need to remove any ' to store words on my database

Comment: Don’t use `addslashes` to sanitize database input! There are much better and safer ways!

Comment: The question description (*after successfully saving in the database, the ' in the string […] is not replaced*) and the follow-up comment (*to remove any '*) contradict each other. But it's clear they correspond to an attempt to address SQL injection. Since this topic is surprisingly badly explained in PHP tutorials and it gets asked here in a daily basis I'll redirect to the reference question where this specific issue is widely covered.